# как создать систему входа на сайт

Tags: python, django

Я уже создал систему регистрации, и теперь хочу создать систему входа, но пока без понятия как это должно работать.

**forms**:

```
from .models import registration, authorization
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput

class registrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = registration
        fields = ["username", "first_name", "second_name", "email", "password", "password2", "date_of_birht"]
        widgets = {
            "username" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputusername4'
                }),
            "first_name" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputName4'
                }),
            "second_name" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputSurname4'
                }),
            "email" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inpuEmail1',
                'placeholder': 'name@example.com'
                }),
            "password" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputPass'
                }),
            "password2" : TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputPass1'
                }),
            "date_of_birht" : TextInput(attrs={
                'style': 'margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 45px; border-radius: 4px;" name="date',
                'id': 'localdate',
                'placeholder': 'День Месяц Год Пример: 12/12/2012',
                'pattern': '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'
                }),

            }
```

**views**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import registrationForm




def auth(request):
    return render(request, 'access/auth.html')


def reg(request):
    # Ошибки
    username_error = ''
    surname_error = ''
    name_error = ''
    email_error = ''
    len_pass_error = ''
    pass_error = ''

    # Список запрещенных символов в имени
    keywords = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '@', '"', '!', '`', '~', '#', '№', ';', '$', '%', '^', ':', '?', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '+', '=', '/']

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = registrationForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        second_name = request.POST.get('second_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')
        date_of_birht = request.POST.get('date_of_birht')
        if password == password2:
            if len(password) >= 8:
                if '@' in email:
                    if not len(first_name) < 2: 
                        if not len(second_name) < 2:
                            if not any(word in first_name for word in keywords):
                                if not any(word in second_name for word in keywords):
                                    if not len(username) < 2 or len(username) > 30:
                                        form.save()
                                        return redirect('/')
                                    else:
                                        username_error = 'Недействительный псевдоним'   
                                else:
                                    surname_error = 'Недействительная фамилия'
                            else:
                                name_error = 'Недействительное имя' 
                        else:
                            surname_error = 'Недействительная фамилия'  
                    else:
                        name_error = 'Недействительное имя'     
                        
                else:   
                    email_error = 'Недействительный адрес электронной почты'    
                
            else:
                len_pass_error = 'Пароль слишком короткий'
                
        else:
            pass_error = 'Пароли не совпадают'


        

            


    form = registrationForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'pass_error' : pass_error,
        'len_pass_error' : len_pass_error,  
        'email_error' : email_error,    
        'name_error' : name_error,
        'surname_error' : surname_error,
        'username_error' : username_error,
    }
    return render(request, 'access/reg.html', context)
```

**models**:

```
from django.db import models

class registration(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField('Псевдоним', max_length = 30)
    first_name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length = 50)
    second_name = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length = 50)
    email = models.CharField('Электронная почта', max_length = 50)
    password = models.CharField('Пароль', max_length = 32)
    password2 = models.CharField('Подтверждение пароля', max_length = 32)
    date_of_birht = models.DateField('Дата рождения')
```

Я долго бродил по просторам интернета, так и не нашел решение, помогите пожалуйста...

Comment: LoginView. Почитай

Comment: будет ли он корректно работать с моей системой регистрации? Ведь в ней я ничего не применял такого

Comment: я просто видел как делают регистрацию с использованием модели User от джанго, но там мне не достаточно полей. Поэтому модель у меня своя

Comment: Смотри, сначала выучи django, так как даже не знаешь что можно расширять модель. Если тебе нужна своя всё-таки по какой-то экзотической причине, то сохраняй данные в куки. А так юзай LoginView, нужны еще поля - расширяй модель

Comment: Вы изобретаете велосипед. Достаточно определить собственную модель для пользователя, унаследовав её от AbstractUser, и вы получите возможность использовать готовые RegistrationView и LoginView. А проверку корректности имени пользователя можно и нужно делать вылидаторами, а не вот этим вот всем.